How to achieve full black shadow and black border in react native?
I want to make my button fully have black border and shadow heres the design how to do that? the problem is the shadow is not fully black, it still have blur effect.

and this is my implementation in react native


  socialButton: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    paddingVertical: 12,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    elevation: 2,
    shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 2},
    shadowOpacity: 1,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    borderRadius: 25,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#000',
  },


<View style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", marginTop: 100 }}>
    <View
      style={{
        width: '90%',
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        borderRadius: 50,
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        height: 70,
        position: "absolute",
        bottom: -6,
        right: 15
      }}>
    </View>
    <View style={{
      width: '90%',
      height: 70,
      borderRadius: 50,
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      borderColor: '#000000',
      borderWidth: 2,
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "center"
    }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: "grey" }}>Title...</Text>
      <Text style={{ color: "#000", fontSize: 22, fontWeight: '700' }}>Message...</Text>
    </View>
  </View>


thank you Tina, looks like your code more cleaner than mine

nvm, i solved it just placing <View> tag behind the button.

import React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  ActivityIndicator,
  View,
  Pressable,
} from 'react-native';
import SvgIcon from '../../../assets/google.svg';
import SvgButton from '../../../assets/Button.svg';

const AtomGoogleButton = ({onPress, loading}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <View
        style={{
          position: 'relative',
        }}>
        <Pressable onPress={onPress} style={styles.socialButton}>
          {loading ? (
            <ActivityIndicator color={'gray'} />
          ) : (
            <>
              <SvgIcon width={24} height={24} />
              <Text style={styles.socialButtonText}>Google</Text>
            </>
          )}
        </Pressable>
        <View
          style={{
            width: '100%',
            paddingVertical: 24,
            paddingHorizontal: 16,
            borderRadius: 25,
            top: 7,
            left: 2,
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            position: 'absolute',
            zIndex: 0,
          }}></View>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  socialButton: {
    // position: 'relative',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    zIndex: 999,
    paddingVertical: 12,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    borderRadius: 25,
    // elevation: 2,
    // shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
    // shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 2},
    // shadowOpacity: 1,
    // shadowRadius: 2,
    borderWidth: 1.5,
    // borderColor: '#000',
  },
  socialButtonText: {
    marginLeft: 8,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'black',
  },
});

export default AtomGoogleButton;


